# Lua deciding to use overloaded _add or _sub

Tags: lua

I created a metatable where __add and __sub take a table and an number. How does Lua determine which to use? Consider the two situations below with table T (with metatable described)

```
local n=-10
local V=T+n
```

and

```
local n=-10
local V=T-n
```

Which gets called?

I have experimented with various combinations but fail to see a pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Created a metatable where __add and __sub take a table and an number.

__add and __sub take *two operands*. One of them will necessarily be a table or userdata which has your metatable, the other can be anything at all. Lua doesn't care about the type of the other operand.

If either operand has a metatable with a handler for the particular operator (`+` -> `__add`, `-` => `__sub`), that handler will be called.

In your example, Lua not only doesn't care if `n` is positive or negative, it doesn't care if it's a number. The `-` in `-n` has nothing to do with the `__sub` metamethod -- that's the *unary* minus operator, whereas `__sub` handles the *binary* minus operator.

> How does Lua determine which to use?

The `+` operator is an "__add" event. When you sayd `op1 + op2`, Lua checks `op1` for a metatable with an `__add` handler. If it finds one, it calls it. Otherwise it checks `op2`.

Answer (score 3):

It is the sign of the two operands operator in the *source code* which is determinant.

It does not care whether the operand value are negative or positive numbers. It does not even care whether your `n` is actually a number or a value of another type.

```
local n=-10  
local V=T+n  -- __add called

local n=-10
local V=T-n  -- __sub called
```